# Error in numbering equation

Tags: equations, numbering

I am using fleqn and align to have the equations in my thesis centered but I noticed that I can't get the correct numbering.

```
    \documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  inner=37.125mm,
  outer=33.4125mm,
  top=1.5cm,
  bottom=1.5cm,
  heightrounded,
 % bindingoffset=0.5cm,
 % marginparwidth=51pt,
 % marginparsep=17pt,
 % headsep=24pt,
}

\begin{document}

\section{One}

Something something something

\subsection{SubSection}

as shown in eq. \eqref{eq:cost_dlp}: 

\begin{fleqn}[\parindent] \label{eq:cost_dlp}
\begin{align}
 & C_{}=C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}    
\end{align}
 \end{fleqn}




\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `fleqn` you ***don't*** have your equations centered.

Comment: also why this fleqn environment rather than the standard fleqn documentclass option?

Comment: Maybe he wants only some  equations to be near the left margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is fairly simple: you didn't put the equation label inside the equation environment, so it refers to the current section. Not related, but if you use `\cref` from `cleveref`, you don't even have to type `equation`. Also, `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions (`cleverref is one of these):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  inner=37.125mm,
  outer=33.4125mm,
  top=1.5cm,
  bottom=1.5cm,
  heightrounded,
 % bindingoffset=0.5cm,
 % marginparwidth=51pt,
 % marginparsep=17pt,
 % headsep=24pt,
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
 \begin{document}

\section{One}

Something something something

\subsection{SubSection}

as shown in \cref{eq:cost_dlp}:

\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{align}\label{eq:cost_dlp}
 & C_{}=C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}
\end{align}
 \end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`\label{…}`always references the last counter being set using `\refstepcounter{…}`.  Display formula counters are stepped at the start of the display, so just put the `\label{…}` inside the formula environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
Something something something
\subsection{SubSection}
as shown in eq. \eqref{eq:cost_dlp}: 

\begin{fleqn}[\parindent] 
    \begin{align}             
        \label{eq:cost_dlp}
        & C_{}=C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}    
    \end{align}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the `\label` at the end of the equation:

```
 & C_{}=C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}+C_\mathrm{}    \label{eq:cost_dlp}
```

If you have more than one equation in the `align`, put the label for each equation just before the `\\` or the end.